# X509Certificate2 on Azure App Services (Azure Websites) since mid-2017?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, x509certificate

I have a .NET Framework 4.7 application that allows users to upload X.509 certificates in PFX or PKCS#12 format (think: "SSL certificates" with the private key included), it then loads the certificate into a `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2` instance. As my application code also needs to re-export the certificate I specify the `X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable` option.

When running under IIS on my production web-server, the Windows user-profile for the identity that `w3wp.exe` runs under is not loaded, so I do not specify the `UserKeySet` flag.

```
String filePassword = ...
Byte[] userProvidedCertificateFile = ...

using( X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2( rawData: userProvidedCertificateFile, password: filePassword, keyStorageFlags: X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet )
{
    ...
}
```

In early 2017 I deployed this code to an Azure App Service (aka Azure Website) instance and it worked okay - after initially failing because I did have the `UserKeySet` flag set (as Azure App Services do not load a user-profile certificate store.

However, since mid-2017 (possibly around May or June) my application has stopped working - I assume the Azure App Service was moved to an updated system (though Kudu reports my application is running on Windows Server 2012 (`NT 6.2.9200.0`).

It currently fails with two error messages that varied depending on input:

- `CryptographicException` "The system cannot find the file specified."
- `CryptographicException` "Access denied."

I wrote an extensive test-case that tries different combinations of `X509Certificate2` constructor arguments, as well as with and without the `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` Azure application setting.

Here are my findings when working with an uploaded PFX/PKCS#12 certificate file that contains a private key and does not have password-protection:

- Running under IIS Express on my development box:

  - Loading the certificate file always succeeds, regardless of `X509KeyStorageFlags` value.
  - Exporting the certificate file requires at least `X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable`.
- Running under IIS on a production server (not an Azure App Service) where the `w3wp.exe` user-profile is not loaded:

  - Loading the certificate file requires that `X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet` is **not** set, but otherwise always succeeds.
  - Exporting the certificate file requires at least `X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable`, but otherwise always succeeds, otherwise it fails with "Key not valid for use in specified state."
- Running under Azure App Service, without `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` defined:

  - Loading the certificate with `MachineKeySet` set and `UserKeySet` is **not** set fails with a `CryptographicException`: "Access denied."
  - Loading the certificate with any other `keyStorageFlags` value, including values like `UserKeySet | MachineKeySet | Exportable` or just `DefaultKeySet` fails with a `CryptographicException`: "The system cannot find the file specified."
  - As I was not able to load the certificate at all I could not test exporting certificates.
- Running under Azure App Service, with `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` defined as the thumbprint of the certificate that was uploaded:

  - Loading the certificate with `MachineKeySet` **and** `UserKeySet` is **not** set, fails with `CryptographicException`: "Access denied." .

    - So values like `UserKeySet` and `UserKeySet | MachineKeySet` and `Exportable` will work.
  - Exporting certificates requires `X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable` - same as all other environments.

So it seems that `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` seems to work - but only if the certificate being loaded into an `X509Certificate2` instance has the same thumbprint as specified in `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES`.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I thought more about how `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` seems to make a difference - but I had a funny feeling about it *really* only working with the certificate thumbprint that's specified.

So I changed the `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` value to a dummy thumbprint - an arbitrary 40-character Base16 string, and re-ran my test - and it worked, even though the thumbprint had no relation to the certificate I was working with.

It seems that simply having `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` defined will enable the the Azure website's ability to use `X509Certificate` and `X509Certificate2` - even if the loaded certificate is never installed into, or even retrieved from, any systemwide or user-profile certificate store (as seen in the Certificates snap-in for MMC.exe).

This behaviour does not seem to be documented anywhere, so I'm mentioning it here.

I've contacted Azure support about this.

Regarding the behavioural change I noticed at mid-year - it's very likely that I did have `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` originally set for a testing certificate we were using. When I made a new deployment later in the year around June I must have reset the *Application settings* which removed the `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` and so broke `X509Certificate2` instances.

### TL;DR:

1. Open your Azure App Service (Azure Website) blade in `portal.azure.com`
2. Go to the **Application settings** page
3. Scroll to **App settings**
4. Add a new entry key: `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES`, and provide a dummy (fake, made-up, randomly-generated) value for it.
5. The `X509Certificate2( Byte[], String, X509KeyStorageFlags )` constructor will now work, but note:

   - `keyStorageFlags: X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet` will fail with "Access denied"
   - All other `keyStorageFlags` values, including `MachineKeySet | UserKeySet` will succeed (i.e. `MachineKeySet` by itself will fail, but `MachineKeySet` used in conjunction with other bits set will work).

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! p.s. the following constructor will also work: X509Certificate2("fileName.pfx", "password")

Comment: [`WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE` will also fix this issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#add-user-profile-support-for-a-site)

Comment: Insane, how did you find this out.. I stumbled into this and weird exceptions I would had never sold without this answer.

Comment: Man you are a genius, we were searching 2 days in the wrong direction. Due to this insane error msg "The system cannot find the file specified."